# Android onActivityResult() doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've got a problem I don't know how to solve.
This is my code of the MainActivity.java which starts a new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AssociationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", json);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Additionaly, I have the following onActivityResult()-method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.print("works outside!");
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            System.out.print("works inside!");
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is where the result should be sent to the MainActivity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", string);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

It seems that the onActivityResult() doesn't even get called as I don't have any output on the console.

In the AndroidManifest.xml I neither use the singleIntent nor the noHistory parameter.

Any suggestions why it doesn't work?

Comment: requestCode 1 not 0 here

Comment: `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` change the 0 for `1` (the request code).

Comment: Okay, I figured out it works, but only at the second time I do this, in the first time nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue, the wasn't any issue at all, I replaced the `System.out` statements with the `Log` from Android it's working all the time, Android just delayed the `System.out`, but I don't know why.
Thanks @Rene Juuse for that tip!

Answer (score 2):

> requestCode change from 1 to 0. as shown below

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.print("works outside!");
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            System.out.print("works inside!");
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even get "works outside!" on the console, it doesn't go into this method

Comment: @Fabian how did you pass the intent back, Did you call the method even?

Comment: I thought this method gets called automatically when the intent gets a result? I use this to give the intent back: `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", string);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();`

Comment: @Fabian It gets called when an acitvity is finished. Did you call the code above? Also make a unique request ID, like `public static int REQUEST_JSON = 12345;` I wouldn't use 0,1... might get into trouble there

Comment: Also stay below 65535, that is the upper limit

Comment: The code above definitely gets called, I checked this with an output on the console.

Comment: Instead of using `System.out` you should be using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: Okay, I figured out it works, but only at the second time I do this, in the first time nothing happens. Any ideas?